# Equivalence of structs? is typealias the "Swift" way to do this?

Tags: swift, struct, enums, equivalence

Maybe I'm over thinking this or having a brain cramp.

```
typealias myZero = reallyLongAndObfuscatedEnum.ZERO
```

Let's say I have some legacy code and need to convert it to Swift 3. This is of course a very simplified version of what I'm dealing with.

```
enum reallyLongAndObfuscatedEnum {

  ///zero
  struct ZERO {
    static let float_t:Float32   = Float32(0)
    static let double_t:Float64  = Float64(0)
    static let cgfloat_t:CGFloat   = CGFloat(0)
    static let desc:String     = "/* nothingness, nada, it is the void  */"
  }
}
```

Now instead of typing:

```
 ReallyLongEquation * reallyLongAndObfuscatedEnum.ZERO.cgfloat_t
```

I can use:

```
ReallyLongEquation * myZero.cgfloat_t
```

Is typealias the "Swift" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are looking for is an alternative (and shorter) name for `reallyLongAndObfuscatedEnum.ZERO`, then yes `typealias` would be the way to go.

At the risk of leading you down the wrong path (since I don't have the full context), you may also want to look at [Associated Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148) in Swift enums. For instance you could rewrite the enum as

```
enum Example {
    case Zero(float_t: 0.0f, double_t: 0.0, cgfloat_t: CGFloat(0))

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Zero:
            return "The Emptiness of Void"
        }
    }
}
```